# Custom UITableViewCell with Progress Bar download update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to update a each table cell with progress bar loading, but I am stuck.
I created a custom cell for a table view with these properties:

```
@interface OFPTableCell : UITableViewCell 
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *detailTextLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@end;
```

and after just @synthesize them, now i have in each table cell a progress bar as expected.

The problem is that when i try to update even 1 st cell with a loading progress bar it just do nothing or its set 0 or full progress bar.
Note that the download process is working fine.

Bellow you may find the code where i try to update the progress bar:

```
 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask          *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:    (int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
      OFPTableCell *cell = (OFPTableCell*)[self tableView:self.tableViewCache    cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.progressView.progress=(double)totalBytesWritten /  (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
});

}
```

Below is the method cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     OFPTableCell *cell = [self.tableViewCache dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];



    OFPVideoDetails *vd = [someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=vd1;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=vd2;

    CGSize size = {65,53};
    cell.imageView.image =[self imageWithImage:[UIImage       imageWithContentsOfFile:vd.imageUrl] scaledToSize:size];



     cell.delegate = self;



 return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very bad practise to call method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`directly, becuase the cell may not exist at the same moment and it may be a cause of the bug you have.

Basically you should do this in another way: add an array of double:

```
double progressValues[30]; // 30 is the count of rows on your tableView, you can set the size dynamically
```

and use it like this:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten 
totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
  OFPTableCell *cell = (OFPTableCell*)[self tableView:self.tableViewCache    cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  progressValues[indexPath.row] = (double)totalBytesWritten /  (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
  [self.tableViewCache reloadData];
});
}
```

and in the dataSource method just add this string:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //... your code...
    cell.progressView.progress = progressValues[indexPath.row];
    // ...
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: One more question instead of [self.tableViewCache reloadData]; i can use [self.tableViewCache reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; ?

Comment: Yes, of course you'd better reload only one row, which changes at the current time. I wrote above just general idea without taking into account such details :)

Comment: I'm getting **nil** in: **cell.progressView.progress = progressValues[indexPath.row];**

Comment: but how to identify for which cell we are showing progressview ?

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the value of (double)totalBytesWritten /  (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite in  OFPVideoDetails (add one property "progress" in OFPVideoDetails).

Then reload the cell in `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask          *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:    (int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OFPTableCell *cell = [self.tableViewCache dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    OFPVideoDetails *vd = [someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=vd1;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=vd2;
    CGSize size = {65,53};
    cell.imageView.image =[self imageWithImage:[UIImage       imageWithContentsOfFile:vd.imageUrl] scaledToSize:size];
    cell.progressView.progress = vd.progress;
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is OFPVideoDetails?

Answer (score 0):

> > For Swift 4.2

```
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

          DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            let cell = self.tableView(self.tableViewCache, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as? OFPTableCell
            progressValues[indexPath.row] = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            self.tableViewCache.reloadData()
        })
    }
```