# Image download in UITableView with UIProgressView Indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, asynchronous

I want to show progress indicator while Asynchronously downloading Image.

I have done it with single image.

But, How I will achieve this in tableView?.Because i'm using **NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate** and getting progress in **URLSession** delegate method.

But,How to perform this in tableView where cell's will be reused,different cell's have different images,all of them will have different progress values...?

Here is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {

var session:NSURLSession?
var downloadTask:NSURLSessionDownloadTask?
var downloadURLString = "imageURL"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var configuration:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("com.app.POCWhatsappLoadingIndicator")

    configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true

    session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    var downloadURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: downloadURLString)!

    var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: downloadURL)

    downloadTask = self.session?.downloadTaskWithRequest(request)

    downloadTask?.resume()

}
```

**Delegate Methods**

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL){

    var fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var URLs:NSArray = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
    var documentsDirectory:NSURL = URLs.objectAtIndex(0) as NSURL
    var fromURL:NSURL = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL
    var destinationURL:NSURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fromURL.lastPathComponent!)
    var error:NSError?


    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(destinationURL, error: nil)

    var success:Bool = fileManager.copyItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURL, error: &error)

    if(success){


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

            var image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: destinationURL.path!)!
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1, 1))
            var context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), image.CGImage)
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.IBDownloadedImage.image = image

            })  
        })  
    }else{
          println("File Copy failed: \(error)")
    }
}


func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){

    var progress:Float = ((Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)))

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        self.updateProgress(progress)

    })

}
```

**Custom Methods**

```
func updateProgress(progress:Float){

    if(progress < 1.0){

        self.IBProgressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

That works fine for Single image.
But how to do for **UITableView.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use **SDWebImage** library with ActivityIndicator. You can get activity indicator and cache of image also.

link : [sdwebimage github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your progress indicator object in UITableViewCell.

Check following answer.
[Custom UITableViewCell with Progress Bar download update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133518/custom-uitableviewcell-with-progress-bar-download-update)

Comment: Yes,i did the same.
But error in **tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)**.
`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

Comment: Can you post your new code so that I can have a look

Comment: Look here...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kkr2cj3smfjmxn/AllImagesViewController.swift?dl=0